# How can I make tomcat logs to rotate and delete via logging.properties?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, catalina

I´m trying to make tomcat to rotate logs every days an delete logs that are older than 20 days.
But they dont rotate and also they don't delete.
I'm trying to know if it is possible to do using logging.properties
I'm using tomcat 9.

I've tried the next way:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.rotatable = true
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 20
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.rotatable = true
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 20
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.rotatable = true
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 20
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.rotatable = true
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 20
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8
```

The rotatable = true, and maxDays = 20 worked for me in server.xml for access_log.

(EDITED)

This is the server.xml that worked for me to manage acces_log:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" rotatable="true" maxDays="20" />
```

Comment: Are you using log4j or some external logging tool? If so it might make sense to use that specific configuration for its own rotation options.

Comment: Hello, No, Im not using anymore to magae those logs. but here i can see the Filehandler documentation and as it says it should allow both, rotate and delete logs. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html

Comment: I see. What about permissions? Does the process you run Tomcat in have read,write,execute permissions on that directory?

Comment: Yes, absolutely